# Add space as split to strings using Java 8 stream (lambdas)

Tags: java, string, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm writing a Xor method which ecnrypts some string by adding (as xor operation) random values to its characters. Result should look like as string with hex values of encrypted characters.

**Example:**

"*Hello world*" => "*0006F 00046 00066 00076 0004D 0007F 00047 0007D 00062 0006E*"

**The code:**

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

inputText.chars()                                      // get char stream
         .filter(c -> c != ' ')                         // remove spaces
         .map(c -> c ^ random.nextInt(randBound))       // do xor for each char
         .boxed()                                       // to Integer stream
         .map(i -> String.format("%05X ", i & 0xFFFFF)) // to Hex String values
         .forEach(sb::append);

if (sb.length() > 0)
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);

return sb.toString();
```

As you see, I've formated the result as `"%05X "`, so I've got unwanted space in the end of string. And need to use `sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);`.

How to format the correct result directly in stream?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want is to collect elements of a Stream into a String. This can be done using [`Collectors.joining(delimiter)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-):

```
inputText.chars() // get char stream
         .filter(c -> c != ' ') // remove spaces
         .map(c -> c ^ random.nextInt(randBound)) // do xor for each char
         .mapToObj(i -> String.format("%05X", i & 0xFFFFF)) // to Hex String values
         .collect(joining(" "));  // join each value together, separated with a space
```

This has the benefit that:

- There's no need to use `forEach` and mutate an external object.
- There's no need to delete the last character.

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); inputText.chars() // get char stream .filter(c -> c != ' ') // remove spaces .map(c -> c ^ random.nextInt(randBound)) // do xor for each char .boxed() // to Integer stream .map(i -> String.format("%05X ", i & 0xFFFFF)) // to Hex String values .forEach(sb::append); if (sb.length() > 0) sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1); return sb.toString();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).